# Applying a function to a DataFrame column returns NoneType

Tags: python, pandas, networking

I have a DataFrame with source IP addresses and I want to check if they belong to a documented CIDR range.

```
netflow_df2["sip"].head(10)

timestamp
2016-10-04 16:24:58    40.101.X.X
2016-10-04 16:24:58    40.101.X.X
2016-10-04 16:24:58     40.101.X.X
2016-10-04 16:24:58     67.X.X.X
2016-10-04 16:24:58        10.1.1.X
2016-10-04 16:24:58      10.1.Y.Y



import ipaddress
import numpy
from collections import defaultdict
from pandas.util.testing import test_parallel
```

I put all the documented CIDRs I know of in a dict:

```
# dict to key (vlan, designation)
nets = defaultdict(str)
nets["10.1.0.0/24"] = "13, web"
net["10.2.0.0/24"] = "14, department X"
net["10.3.55.0/24"] = "601, wifi"
...
net["10.1.243.0/24"] = "1337, IT"
```

I define my function:

```
def netmap(ip, network_lookup_dict):
    for key, value in network_lookup_dict.iteritems() :
        if ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(ip)) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(key)):
            return value
            # print "VLAN: " + infos[0].strip() + ", Network designation: " + infos[1].strip()
        else:
            return numpy.NAN
```

And now I map it:

```
@test_parallel(num_threads=4)
def apply_netmap(netflow_df2, location="ABC"):
    % time netflow_df2["sip_infos"] = netflow_df2["sip"].map(lambda ip: netmap(ip, nets))
    return netflow_df2


CPU times: user 3min 14s, sys: 21.2 s, total: 3min 36s
Wall time: 3min 5s


netflow_df3 = apply_netmap(netflow_df2)
```

My error is:

```
netflow_df3.head(10)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

I was under the impression this function would map the return value of `netmap()` to the DataFrame column. That is the reason why I also return `NAN`. This does not appear to be the case. Also it's super slow.

Comment: your function needs to have a 'return netflow_df2'

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error.

Comment: what is this for:  if ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(ip)) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(key))

Comment: I want to figure out if the IP is in the CIDR range from the dict

Comment: You should separate these into two steps and without any functions. Your second step should check if the IP is in the CIDR range. In the first step, 'time netflow_df2["sip_infos"] = netflow_df2["sip"].map(network_lookup_dict)'

Comment: I can't map the IP (source IP), because the dict only contains network ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I use the `defaultdict` in the `netmap` function wrong. This yields the corrects results:

```
def netmap(ip, network_lookup_dict):
    for key, value in network_lookup_dict.iteritems(): 
        try:
            if ipaddress.ip_address(unicode(ip)) in ipaddress.ip_network(unicode(key)):
                return network_lookup_dict.get(key)
        except KeyError:
            print "duh"
            return numpy.NaN
```

The `return` statement was broken. It's confusing to me why this would corrupt the `DataFrame` object, but I suppose everything has bugs.